# xlrd - append data to already opened workbook

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to write a python program for appending live stock quotes from a csv file to an excel file (which is already open) using xlrd and xlwt.

The task is summarised below.

From my stock-broker's application, a csv file is continually being updated on my hard disk.
I wish to write a program which, when run, would append the new data from csv file to an excel file, which is kept open (I wonder whether it is possible to read & write an open file).

I wish to keep the file open because I will be having stock-charts in it.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.  xlutils can use xlrd and xlwt to copy a spreadsheet, and appending to a "to be written" worksheet is straightforward.  I don't think reading the open spreadsheet is a problem -- but xlwt will not write to the open book/sheet.

You might write an Excel VBA macro to draw the graphs.  In principle, I think a macro from a command workbook could close your stock workbook, invoke your python code to copy and update, open the new spreadsheet, and maybe run the macro to re-draw the graphs.

Another approach is to use matplotlib for the graphs.  I'd think a sleep loop could wake up every n seconds, grab the new csv data, append it to your "big" csv data, and re-draw the graph.  Taking this approach keeps you in python and should make things a lot easier, imho.  Disclosure: my Python is better than my VBA.

Comment: Since the workbook is to be refreshed every minute, I would avoid closing & re-opening the workbook every time. Regarding VBA macro:-- Drawing graph in excel is like snatching a candy from a kid. In chart-wizard, I select a large cell-range for data (where it will be populated in real-time).    Regarding matplotlib:-- Since good chart options are already available in Excel & open-office, why to re-invent the wheel using matplotlib?

Comment: Any inputs on using excel option of 'get external data'?

Comment: If open workbook can't be written to, the is it possible to insert worksheet to an already opened workbook?   In that case, I would keep the chart on one sheet and data on another sheet. For refreshing, delete the data-worksheet and insert new sheet with same name. This sheet will have the updated data.